# Is there a way to perform complex filters on object sets without coding a function?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I would like to generate an object set from the results of a complex filter that involves aggregates and then perform an Action on that object set.

Currently, I am using Quiver transform tables to perform the filter. However, it doesn't look like you can then use the results of a transform table in Quiver to filter an object set.

The only other alternative looks to be writing a Function to filter the data to generate a new object set.

Is a function the only way or is there a no-code solution?

Comment: Can you provide a notional example of the logic you want to use in the filter? There might be a way to do this, but it'd be easier to help with some more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can do this by reducing a column in the Transform Table (TT) into an array, which can then be used to filter the Object Set (OSF).

**Details:**

1. Start with your input object set (OSI)
2. Add a Transform Table (TT). Add whatever transformation and filter logic you want.
3. With the TT selected, under the "Convert" menu that appears below a board when you select that board, choose one of the "Transform table column values" boards. Pick the right one for the data type you're going to use to filter the object set. The result will be a single array of values.
4. Select OSI and add a Filter board. Pick the property you want to filter on (e.g. "...where someProperty is"). Instead of inputting a static value, click on the type selector and choose the array you created in the previous step. Now you'll have your filtered object set (OSF).

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can use that resulting object set in Workshop. I'd like to be able to execute actions on that resulting set.

Comment: You can access the object set by (1) adding the corresponding board in the Quiver analysis to a Quiver Dashboard, adding an "Output" to that dashboard (your object set), and saving that dashboard; (2) adding a Quiver Dashboard widget to your Workshop module; (3) creating a new object set var from the dashboard output. If you want to hide the dashboard, then you can give it an absolute height of 0.

Comment: You're welcome! I might make this into a video for my Foundry Tutorials series...it's fairly advanced and tricky to follow in just text.